# Count specific value of total beetwen two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to prepare a query that will calculate specific values with data in a certain range.

For example, what percentage of total is "serwis" in the 2017-01-01 - 2017-12-31 range.

I manage to filter the number of queries in a given range, but the ratio is still calculated from the total.

Where am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT serwis, COUNT(*) AS Total,
       (COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM serwis)) * 100 AS 'procent'
FROM serwis 
WHERE serwis = 'Tak' AND kalendarz >= '2017-01-01' AND kalendarz <= '2017-12-31'
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Is `serwis` the name of a table, a column, or a value in a column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff "serwis" and "kalendarz" is a name of column.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total,
       SUM(kalendarz >= '2017-01-01' AND kalendarz <='2017-12-31') as TotalInRange,
       AVG(kalendarz >= '2017-01-01' AND kalendarz <= '2017-12-31') as proprtionInRange
FROM serwis 
WHERE serwis = 'Tak';
```

Comment: I would like to refer WHERE serwis = 'Tak' only to the average.